# Cannot initialize a parameter of type "const unsigned char *" with an rvalue of type 'value_type *' (aka char*)

Tags: c++, c, cocos2d-x

I get an error "Cannot initialize a parameter of type "const unsigned char *" with an rvalue of type 'value_type *' (aka char*)" in the following lines.

```
image->initWithImageData(&(buffer->front()),buffer->size());
```

buffer is of type `std::vector<char> *buffer`

and the above error in on `&(buffer->front()` does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: `unsigned char*` and `char*` are 2 different types. could you change `buffer` to `std::vector<unsigned char> *buffer`

Answer (score 3):

The const is not a problem, but you need to cast the pointer - this isn't recommended generally but if you don't have another choice, you can do one of the following

```
char *a = buffer->data();
const unsigned  char *b= reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(a);
```

or plain C style

```
const unsigned  char *b= (const unsigned  char *)(a);
```